# Reduce database request of rails exists? method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have to render the latest 14 posts in the index page.
In order to avoid users upvoting a post more than one time and preventing the post creator to vote.

I did this to not showing the upvote link(in views level):

```
if !(post.upvotes.exists?(:user_id => current_user.id) or post.user_id == current_user.id)
```

However, every time I reload the index page, it sends requests like this for 14 times.

```
Upvote Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "upvotes"  WHERE "upvotes"."post_id" = $1 AND "upvotes"."user_id" = 2 LIMIT 1  [["post_id", 22]]
```

I am just wondering if this is common and I really want to know if there are better ways to achieve the same result whilst reducing the database query.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem I guess is N+1 queries, see this link [Active Record eager_load](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations).

With eager load you can have 2 queries to DB, 1 for all posts and 1 for all related upvotes.

Now you have 1 query for all posts, then for every post you get 1 query for all upvotes for that particular post.

example

```
# in controller you do something like
@posts = Post.condition

# to add eager load do next
@posts = Post.includes(:upvotes).condition # this will load all related upvotes for all posts
# you don't have to eager load users, because you don't handle user object,
# you are checking if user_id that is already loaded with upvotes object,
# s matching current_user.id, you are not fetching user object from DB
# ---
# use this
# this way you work with loaded data instead of making request to DB to check 
# if exsits upvotes with user_id == current_user.id
if !(post.upvotes.map(&:user_id).include?(current_user.id) || post.user_id == current_user.id)


# instead of
if !(post.upvotes.exists?(:user_id => current_user.id) or post.user_id == current_user.id)
# when you use method exists? rails will make new query to DB even if you eager load data
```

Comment: I changed to : @posts = Post.includes(:upvotes, :user).all.last(14).reverse and it still sends 14 queries.

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit its ugly, but I hope it can be helpful:

```
@posts = Post.joins(:upvotes).where('upvotes.user_id = ?', current_user.id).group('posts.id').having('COUNT(upvotes.id) > 0')
```

I've try that on some of my models and it worked.